# How to create a method which invokes another service and return a Future?

Tags: scala, future

I want to define a method, which will return a `Future`. And in this method, it will call another service which returns also a `Future`.

We have defined a `BusinessResult` to represent `Success` and `Fail`:

```
object validation {
  trait BusinessResult[+V] {
    def flatMap[T](f: V => BusinessResult[T]):BusinessResult[T]
    def map[T](f: V => T): BusinessResult[T]
  }

  sealed case class Success[V](t:V) extends BusinessResult[V] {
    def flatMap[T](f: V => BusinessResult[T]):BusinessResult[T] = {
      f(t)
    }
    def map[T](f: V => T): BusinessResult[T] = {
      Success(f(t))
    }
  }

  sealed case class Fail(e:String) extends BusinessResult[Nothing] {
    def flatMap[T](f: Nothing => BusinessResult[T]):BusinessResult[T] = this
    def map[T](f: Nothing => T): BusinessResult[T] = this
  }

}
```

And define the method:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import validation._

def name: BusinessResult[String] = Success("my name")

def externalService(name:String):Future[String] = future(name)

def myservice:Future[Int] = {
  for {
    n <- name
    res <- externalService(n)
  } yield res match {
    case "ok" => 1
    case _ => 0
  }
}
```

But which is not compilable. The code in `myservice` can't return a `Future[Int]` type.

I also tried to wrap the `name` with `Future`:

```
def myservice:Future[Int] = {
  for {
    nn <- Future.successful(name)
    n <- nn
    res <- externalService(n)
  } yield res match {
    case "ok" => 1
    case _ => 0
  }
}
```

Which is also not compilable.

I know there must be a lot of issues in this code. How can I adjust them to make it compilable?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the `n` with some hardcoded string it works, the problem is that in the for comprehension the variable `n` has type `BusinessResult[String]`, as you probably already know for comprehension desugarize to `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` so the first part `n <- name` desugarize to a `map` on name:

```
val test: BusinessResult[String] = name.map(x => x)
```

Intellij thinks `n` is a `String` but the scala compiler disagree:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : validation.BusinessResult[Nothing]
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[Int]
[error]       n <- name
[error]         ^
```

Easy solution could be to add a getter method to get back the string and do something like `Option` does:

```
object validation {
  trait BusinessResult[+V] {
    def flatMap[T](f: V => BusinessResult[T]):BusinessResult[T]
    def map[T](f: V => T): BusinessResult[T]
    def getVal: V
  }

  sealed case class Success[V](t:V) extends BusinessResult[V] {
    def flatMap[T](f: V => BusinessResult[T]):BusinessResult[T] = {
      f(t)
    }
    def map[T](f: V => T): BusinessResult[T] = {
      Success(f(t))
    }
    def getVal: V = t
  }

  sealed case class Fail(e:String) extends BusinessResult[Nothing] {
    def flatMap[T](f: Nothing => BusinessResult[T]):BusinessResult[T] = this
    def map[T](f: Nothing => T): BusinessResult[T] = this
    def getVal = throw new Exception("some message")
  }
}

def myservice: Future[Int] = {
  val value = name.getVal
  for {
    res <- externalService(value)
  } yield res match {
    case "ok" => 1
    case _ => 0
  }
}
```

Note that you can't extract the name in the for comprehension since `map` on `String` return `Char`s

Comment: If `name` is a `Fail`, `val value = name.getVal` will throw exception, which is not expected

Comment: I just added an example implementation, what would you expect if it was a `Fail`? As you probably know `Option` has the `getOrElse` method, you could also use something like that. The problem here is how to unwrap the custom type you have, that means also to have to deal with possible exceptions, I just mentioned Options because they have very nice ways to unwrap a value they hold.